# Can a multiple choice test reliably measure decision making speed?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, validation, selection-recruitment

Are there any studies showing that there is a direct connection (or a lack of a connection) between performance on a speeded, written, multiple choice test, and making quick decisions during a critical incident?